# How to make MATLAB play an array faster?

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, matlab, audio-processing

I'm working on a audio processor, which is supposed to change the pitch and add a vibrato to a song while it is playing. Note that, although the sound isn't live (e.g. from a microphone) the effects that I want to add are to be made in real time.

I found that the best way to approach it would be dividing the soundfile into small elements and apply the effects on each one by order.

So I wrote this to divide the audio file:

```
%Load Sound File
[fsample Fs] = wavread ('C:\Users\Ogulcan\Desktop\Bitirme Projesi\Codes\kravitz.wav'); 


%length of the sample
t=length(fsample);
%number of samples
ns=10;
%Defining the array:
A=[];


%Create the vectors and place them into the array 'A':

for i=1:ns-1
   v=fsample(i*t/ns:(i+1)*t/ns);
   A=[A;v];
end
```

This code works and divides the sound into 10 samples, however when I try to play them in a loop there is a small but noticable delay. Now I plan on doing this for a lot bigger sample numbers.

Can anyone help me with this speed issue? I really don't know any other language than MATLAB or have the required software, so I would appreciate if you could show me a way to do this in MATLAB.

Comment: Matlab is interpreted language so looping is slow. This could be the reason. However, can you post the code you use to play the samples?

Comment: I don't think that this has to do with the speed of the loops. I think this is an issue with `wavplay`/`audioplayer` when trying to play two samples back to back.

Comment: @EitanT is right: you can't do this properly with just a loop and MATLAB's basic sound functions. I believe [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/) has sound functions that allow you to write more directly to the audio stream, which should allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the entire loop with the following simpler snippet:

```
A = fsample(1:end-rem(length(fsample),ns));  % ensure data has ns full samples
A = reshape(A,[],ns)';
```

Comment: though this is indeed a more elegant way to create A, I suspect that the problem lies in the actual back-to-back playing of the various samples.

Comment: @Yair I tried your suggestion however I got an error message that says

Product of known dimensions, 10, not divisible into
total number of elements, 328042.

Does anyone have any idea on why this could have happened and how I could fix it? Thank you in advance. 
(I hope this is the way to reply comments I couldn't see a reply button)

Comment: That's what the first line is for - to ensure that A has a devisible number of elements without remainder, so that you could then safely reshape it into a matrix. In your case, A would have 328040 elements (last 2 would be discarded).